# How to get a session_id, its start and end time and bot_id in python with Telegram Bot API?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

I'm making a Telegram Bot in Python with the help of Telegram Bot API. So I want to keep some information about the Telegram Chat in SQLite database and i need to get message_id, message_time, session_id, session_start_time, session_end_time, message_text and user/bot_id. So I've found how to get message_id, message_time, message_text and user_id. But can't find how to get the other.

1. How do I get session_id and its start and end time and bot_id? I've looked it up in the documentation and found nothing.
2. How to insert both user_id and bot_id in the same column or it's better to make 2 columns for that? Like it doesn't matter who sent the message, most important is that the message was sent.
   That's what I came up with so far:

```
    conn = sqlite3.connect("emojic_database.db")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    tconv = lambda x: time.strftime("%H:%M:%S %d.%m.%Y", time.localtime(x))
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO messages (mes_id, mes_time, ses_id, mes_text, user_id)\
                    VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)", (message.message_id, tconv(message.date), ???, message.text, message.from_user.id)
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO sessions (ses_id, start_time, end_time)\
                    VALUES (?,?,?)", (???))
    conn.close()
```

Or maybe I have to use another API? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered a usage of any library builded upon the Telegram API? Development will go much faster and those library's documentations also help to understand Telegram API.

Check for example:

- https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/ (actually the best on my opinion)
- https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki (good documentation but it doesn't support async)
- https://github.com/aiogram/aiogram

Comment: Thanks, just as I thought it's better to use telethon instead.